# Invalid value entry in Sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I get user values ​​from webview via @JavascriptInterface, there is no problem with this.

Next I record the obtained values ​​in preferences, for their further use.
However, as Logs shows, values ​​are not written correctly.

What am I wrong about?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    SharedPreferences sPref;
    public static final String PREFS_FILE = "MyPrefsFile";

    ................

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showUser(String data) {
            Log.d("MyTAG", "INPUT: "+data);
            ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    stringArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
                    Log.d("MyTAG", "i="+i+" :"+jsonArray.getString(i));
                }
                Log.d("MyTAG", "Array: "+stringArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            sPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, 0);

            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
            ed.putString(NAME,stringArray.get(0));
            ed.putString(AVATAR,stringArray.get(1));
            ed.putString(USER_ID, stringArray.get(2));

            ed.commit();


            Log.d("MyTAG", "name="+sPref.getString(NAME, ""));
            Log.d("MyTAG", "avatar="+sPref.getString(AVATAR, ""));
            Log.d("MyTAG", "user_id="+sPref.getString(USER_ID, ""));

        }

    }


}
```

Logs:

```
D/MyTAG: INPUT: ["myname","src","2"]

D/MyTAG: i=0 :myname
D/MyTAG: i=1 :src
D/MyTAG: i=2 :2

D/MyTAG: Array: [myname, src, 2]

D/MyTAG: name=src
D/MyTAG: avatar=src
D/MyTAG: user_id=2
```

For some reason, the meaning changes to the following.

How to get preferences value `name = myname`

Comment: Please show your definitions for `NAME`, `AVATAR`, and `USER_ID`.

Comment: final String NAME = "";
    final String AVATAR = "";
    final String USER_ID = "1";

Comment: @greeble31 You are right, set non-empty values, and now everything is OK :) Thanks for the help!  `final String NAME = "guest";`
    `final String AVATAR = "no";`
    `final String USER_ID = "1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//SharedPreferences key names:
final String NAME = "name";
final String AVATAR = "avatar";
final String USER_ID = "user_id";
```

You see, what gets passed to `putString()/getString()` is the *contents* of the variable. The name for the variable itself (e.g., `AVATAR`) is inconsequential.

When you passed the empty string ("") for both `NAME` and `AVATAR`, the `SharedPreferences` thought you were referencing the entry called "". So you thought you had two discrete entries, but really you only had one, with the same name, and they were clobbering each other.

The values you choose as the key names (e.g., "name", "avatar", "user_id") are arbitrary, but they are written to the `SharedPreferences` file, and will be visible to anyone reading that file in a text editor. For that reason, it helps to choose descriptive values.